# Is there a ON / OFF component integrated into ember bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I would like to use this [switch component](http://www.larentis.eu/switch) in my ember views:

Specifically, I want to use the following features:

- set the colors, like: `data-on="success" data-off="warning"`
- default animation settings
- default size
- configure the text values for <kbd>ON</kbd> / <kbd>OFF</kbd> (I want to use it for and <kbd>Away</kbd> / <kbd>Online</kbd> parameter), like: `data-on-label="Online" data-off-label="Away"`

Is there something similar already integrated into ember-bootstrap? Would it be difficult to integrate that? I have no experience coding for ember-bootstrap, but I would be willing to contribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you. Simple toggle switch in ember

http://hawkins.io/2013/07/ember-toggle-switch/

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting. It is not so flexible as the switch component I linked to (not possible to configure the text of the switch, for example), but I will use it for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project [bootstrap-switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) and couple of its integrations with ember:

1. [ember-cli-bootstrap-switch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-bootstrap-switch)
2. [ember-bootstrap-switch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-bootstrap-switch)

I liked `ember-bootstrap-switch` more. Despite the name it supports ember-cli as well.
`ember-cli-bootstrap-switch` at the time I looked into it does not provide a way to change labels, but in the latest version it seems that this was fixed.